# ggplot2's line legends appear "crossed-out"

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, charts, legend

I'm creating a ggplot with two lines, each from separate geoms. As an example:

```
df = data.frame(
   x.v = seq(0, 1, 0.025),
   y.v = runif(41)
)
straight.line = data.frame(
   Inter = c(0),
   Slope = c(1)
)

p = ggplot() +
   geom_point(
      mapping = aes(
         x = x.v,
         y = y.v
      ),
      data = df,
      colour = "blue"
   ) +
   geom_smooth(
      mapping = aes(
         x = x.v,
         y = y.v,
         colour = "line of best fit"
      ),
      data = df,
      method = "lm",
      show.legend = NA
   ) +
   geom_abline(
      mapping = aes(
         intercept = Inter,
         slope = Slope,
         colour = "y = x"
      ),
      data = straight.line,
     show.legend = NA
   ) +
   guides(
      fill = "none",
      linetype = "none",
      shape = "none",
      size = "none"
   )
```

This gives the output:

[image: Output of the above code]

As you can see, the legend has weird diagonal lines through it. An [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53355332/9976891) says this can be fixed by using `show.legend = NA`. However, as you can see in the code above, I did this and it did not change the result.

Does anybody know what is adding the diagonal lines in the legend and how else I can fix it please? Thanks.

EDIT: A question of if this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25294604/9976891). This may be the answer but how do I apply this when the answer in the link uses fill, and I use colour, please?

If I try

```
+ guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL)))
```

I get the error

```
Error in check.length("col") : 'gpar' element 'col' must not be length 0
```

and if I try

```
+ guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = listfill = NULL)))
```

I get the error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "fill", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1
```

Comment: Use `show.legend = FALSE` and not `show.legend = NA`.

Comment: @Neoromanzer : thanks, just tried that and didn't work

Comment: @kath : that just stopped the legend from showing up at all

Comment: Use `show.legend = FALSE` only in the `geom_abline` call. Then the color legend is still there but without the line crossing.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x.v, y = y.v),
             data = df, colour = "blue") +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = x.v, y = y.v, colour = "line of best fit"),
              data = df, method = "lm", show.legend = NA) +
  geom_abline(mapping = aes(intercept = Inter, slope = Slope, colour = "y = x"),
              data = straight.line, show.legend = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = "none", linetype = "none",  shape = "none", size = "none")
```

The code can be made a little bit less repetitive and we can leave out some things (liek the `guide`-call):

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = x.v, y = y.v)) +
  geom_point(colour = "blue") +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = "line of best fit"), method = "lm") +
  geom_abline(mapping = aes(intercept = Inter, slope = Slope, colour = "y = x"),
              data = straight.line, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Why do we need to use `show.legend = FALSE` here and not `show.legend = NA`?

From the documentation:

*show.legend*

*logical. Should this layer be included in the legends? NA, the default, includes if any aesthetics are mapped. FALSE never includes, and TRUE always includes. It can also be a named logical vector to finely select the aesthetics to display*

This means that is we use `show.legend = NA` for the `geom_abline`-call we use this layer in the legend. However, we don't want to use this layer and therefore need `show.legend = FALSE`. You can see that this does not influence, which colors are included in the legend, only the layer.

**Data**

```
set.seed(42) # For reproducibilty
df = data.frame(x.v = seq(0, 1, 0.025),
                y.v = runif(41))
straight.line = data.frame(Inter = 0, Slope = 1)
```